# i have created a project in sentry on react but configuring it on gatsby is it a correct way to do?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, sentry, gatsby-plugin

I am using sentry to track crashing report and I have setup my project on top of react but I am configuring it by Gatsby and I have added the plugin in correct way in gatsby.js file but on creating issue in any one of the component it is not reflecting on sentry issue and I am not able to find the reason of this problem. Please help me out

I am putting error-boundary.js file inside my component folder and here is the code of that

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { ErrorBoundary } from '@sentry/react';
    import { Link } from 'gatsby';
    
    const FallBack = ({ error, resetError }) => (
        <div role="alert">
            <p>Something went wrong:</p>
            <pre>{error.message}</pre>
            <Link to="/" onClick={resetError}>
                <a>Try again</a>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
    
    const ErrorBoundaryContainer = ({ children }) => {
        return <ErrorBoundary fallback={FallBack}>{children}</ErrorBoundary>;
    };
    
    export default ErrorBoundaryContainer;
```

and then I am importing it in gatsby-browser.js file

```
        import React from 'react'
        import ErrorBoundaryContainer from './src/components/error-boundary'
    
        export const wrapPageElement = ({ element }) => (
          <ErrorBoundaryContainer>
        {element}
          </ErrorBoundaryContainer>
    )
```

and then I am creating a case in one of my component to throw error for testing,

```
 

    const [toggle, toggleError] = React.useState(false);
      if (toggle) {
            console.error('console error');
            throw new Error('I crashed!');
        }
    <button type="button" onClick={() => toggleError(true)}>
                        Break the world
                    </button>
```

Comment: Can you provide at least how are you trying to set the error boundary?

Comment: i am following this https://chrisotto.dev/gatsby-error-monitoring-with-sentry/ to setup error boundary but i am not able to understand that how to put it up in layout

Comment: Can you provide **your** implementation rather than the guide you've followed? What have you tried? Where's the code that is not working? You've **only** shared a screenshot of your Sentry dashboard, how do you think we can help you with the information provided?

Comment: @FerranBuireu i have updated questions with the code that i have written in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to comment here:

- `wrapPageElement` is a shared API between [`gatsby-browser.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapPageElement) and [`gatsby-ssr.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/#wrapPageElement) so if you use it, you must place the same snippet in both files
- I'm assuming you used `@sentry/gatsby` as a dependency, as the [docs suggests](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/gatsby/)
- The component that is throwing the error should contain a `useEffect`, otherwise, it will never throw the error. It's a React mistake, not Gatsby.

  ```
       const [toggle, toggleError] = React.useState(false);

       React.useEffect(()=>{
         if (toggle) {
            console.error('console error');
            throw new Error('I crashed!');
         }
       }, [toggle])

    <button type="button" onClick={() => toggleError(!toggle)}>Break the world </button>
  ```

  *Note: if it's a toggle, it should change to the opposite value, isn't it? Tweak it as you wish of course*

  The `useEffect` hook with a `toggle` dependencies (`[toggle]`) will be fired each change the toggle value changes. In your snippet, because initially is set to `false` (`React.useState(false)`) your error was never thrown. It's like saying "Ok, when my deps value (`toggle` in this case) changes, fire what I have inside".

Comment: I have made these changes but still issue is not getting listed in sentry and I am not able to find out what else is missing

Comment: If you are not able to find out imagine the rest of us xD. Can you debug a little bit? Can you ensure that the `useEffect` is being fired and the `div role="alert"` is surrounding the HTML?

Comment: finally it is working now, thankyou for your guidance and support cheers!